# XPath query to find an attribute of a node based on an attribute of another node in a different part of the file

Tags: xpath, openstreetmap

I have an xml file generated by Open Street Map. In it are "node" nodes and "way" nodes.

The "node" nodes are at the top of the file, and the "way" nodes further down. The "node" nodes contain latitude and longitude (as attributes) information for a point. The "way" nodes contain a list of "nd" nodes that make up the way. The @ref attribute of each "nd" node matches the @id attribute of a "node".

I need to parse the xml for each /way/nd/@ref and get @latitude and @longitude from the corresponding "node"

Essentially I want to have a list of ways with latitude and longitude values for each node in the way.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Ive tried dozens of combinations of xpath queries to try to make it work but can't seem to pin it down.

Example xml follows, If anyone is interested, I'm doing this to import the "ways" into a drupal site to plot the "ways" on an openlayers map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. It has there been collected by a large group of contributors. For individual attribution of each item please refer to http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/[node|way|relation]/#id/history </note>
<meta osm_base="2012-09-12T07:00:02Z"/>

  <node id="291435953" lat="50.7468739" lon="7.1563067" version="4" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="291435954" lat="50.7464770" lon="7.1561995" version="2" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="291435955" lat="50.7461387" lon="7.1558430" version="2" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <tag k="highway" v="turning_circle"/>
  </node>
  <node id="291435956" lat="50.7472300" lon="7.1555832" version="3" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:32Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="291435957" lat="50.7462073" lon="7.1544363" version="1" timestamp="2008-08-26T21:58:25Z" changeset="418638" uid="36773" user="bernd1606">
    <tag k="created_by" v="JOSM"/>
  </node>
  <node id="291438870" lat="50.7479387" lon="7.1562447" version="4" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:31Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <tag k="highway" v="turning_circle"/>
  </node>
  <node id="291438872" lat="50.7476693" lon="7.1540409" version="1" timestamp="2008-08-26T22:05:07Z" changeset="418638" uid="36773" user="bernd1606">
    <tag k="created_by" v="JOSM"/>
  </node>
  <node id="470930364" lat="50.7466304" lon="7.1550088" version="1" timestamp="2009-08-19T10:27:27Z" changeset="2198882" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226020" lat="50.7462970" lon="7.1551053" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:35Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226026" lat="50.7461263" lon="7.1552748" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:35Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226027" lat="50.7460993" lon="7.1549555" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:35Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226028" lat="50.7463885" lon="7.1540406" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:35Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226035" lat="50.7460590" lon="7.1549115" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:36Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226040" lat="50.7460307" lon="7.1549335" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:37Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226041" lat="50.7461886" lon="7.1551879" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:37Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226043" lat="50.7460489" lon="7.1552923" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:37Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226044" lat="50.7465142" lon="7.1543804" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:37Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226049" lat="50.7461296" lon="7.1549315" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:38Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226065" lat="50.7461674" lon="7.1552133" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:39Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226068" lat="50.7460541" lon="7.1546925" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:39Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226069" lat="50.7462755" lon="7.1542526" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:39Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226071" lat="50.7461058" lon="7.1548565" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:39Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226087" lat="50.7462284" lon="7.1551919" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:40Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226090" lat="50.7461464" lon="7.1550496" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:40Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226091" lat="50.7465509" lon="7.1541410" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:40Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226104" lat="50.7460048" lon="7.1551556" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:41Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226127" lat="50.7462070" lon="7.1544275" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:43Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226133" lat="50.7461004" lon="7.1550786" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:43Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226142" lat="50.7460609" lon="7.1548346" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:44Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226144" lat="50.7461532" lon="7.1553573" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:44Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226149" lat="50.7460912" lon="7.1548105" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:44Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226165" lat="50.7461320" lon="7.1546332" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:45Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226171" lat="50.7462548" lon="7.1549671" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:45Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226180" lat="50.7460253" lon="7.1549160" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:46Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226184" lat="50.7462552" lon="7.1552743" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:46Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226192" lat="50.7461445" lon="7.1552153" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:47Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226196" lat="50.7460206" lon="7.1547882" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:47Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226197" lat="50.7461830" lon="7.1548005" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:47Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1212226208" lat="50.7465204" lon="7.1542470" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:48Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1558201806" lat="50.7465619" lon="7.1543799" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:53Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1558201807" lat="50.7465706" lon="7.1545076" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:53Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1558201808" lat="50.7465787" lon="7.1542431" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:53Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1558201809" lat="50.7465945" lon="7.1546459" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:53Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1558201810" lat="50.7466379" lon="7.1540966" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:53Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1558201813" lat="50.7468171" lon="7.1569205" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:54Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1558201814" lat="50.7469049" lon="7.1557857" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:33Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1558201822" lat="50.7472431" lon="7.1542901" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:31Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1558201829" lat="50.7478716" lon="7.1567219" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:54Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw"/>
  <node id="1579451712" lat="50.7475476" lon="7.1550423" version="2" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:32Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1647096049" lat="50.7477273" lon="7.1555526" version="1" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:31Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1647096076" lat="50.7468682" lon="7.1556378" version="1" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:32Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1647096079" lat="50.7469025" lon="7.1560030" version="2" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:39Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1751820951" lat="50.7469115" lon="7.1558916" version="1" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:39Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1751820952" lat="50.7465981" lon="7.1562371" version="1" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1751820953" lat="50.7463604" lon="7.1561245" version="1" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1751820954" lat="50.7462630" lon="7.1560233" version="1" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <node id="1751820955" lat="50.7461938" lon="7.1559261" version="1" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67"/>
  <way id="26577114" version="3" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:40Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="291435953"/>
    <nd ref="1751820952"/>
    <nd ref="291435954"/>
    <nd ref="1751820953"/>
    <nd ref="1751820954"/>
    <nd ref="1751820955"/>
    <nd ref="291435955"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="RhedenstraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="26577115" version="2" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:12:55Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw">
    <nd ref="1558201814"/>
    <nd ref="291435956"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="26577275" version="4" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:32Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="291438870"/>
    <nd ref="1647096049"/>
    <nd ref="1579451712"/>
    <nd ref="1558201822"/>
    <nd ref="1558201815"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Mutter-Barat-StraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="26577276" version="3" timestamp="2012-02-25T15:00:30Z" changeset="10788449" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="291438871"/>
    <nd ref="291438872"/>
    <nd ref="1647095991"/>
    <nd ref="1647095994"/>
    <nd ref="291438873"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="StegerwaldstraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="31347483" version="6" timestamp="2012-02-25T14:04:08Z" changeset="10787922" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1558201825"/>
    <nd ref="96133774"/>
    <nd ref="1647008854"/>
    <nd ref="1558201826"/>
    <nd ref="1558201827"/>
    <nd ref="96133775"/>
    <nd ref="1558201829"/>
    <nd ref="1558201831"/>
    <nd ref="96133776"/>
    <nd ref="1558201832"/>
    <nd ref="291438874"/>
    <nd ref="1558201836"/>
    <nd ref="96133777"/>
    <nd ref="291089398"/>
    <nd ref="96133778"/>
    <nd ref="32346787"/>
    <nd ref="291089396"/>
    <nd ref="291092263"/>
    <nd ref="33078442"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Alte SchulstraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="39300712" version="3" timestamp="2011-10-30T13:18:29Z" changeset="9693579" uid="239847" user="theophrastus">
    <nd ref="470930364"/>
    <nd ref="1212226113"/>
    <nd ref="470930365"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Alaunbach"/>
    <tag k="waterway" v="stream"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196611" version="2" timestamp="2011-05-26T14:50:40Z" changeset="8254295" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226149"/>
    <nd ref="1212226142"/>
    <nd ref="1212226027"/>
    <nd ref="1212226049"/>
    <nd ref="1212226071"/>
    <nd ref="1212226149"/>
    <tag k="building" v="garages"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196614" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:50Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226065"/>
    <nd ref="1212226220"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="service"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196615" version="2" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:21:18Z" changeset="7630100" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226068"/>
    <nd ref="1212226149"/>
    <nd ref="1212226071"/>
    <nd ref="1212226197"/>
    <nd ref="1212226165"/>
    <nd ref="1212226068"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Bonn"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="21a"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="53229"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196617" version="2" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:21:18Z" changeset="7630100" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226067"/>
    <nd ref="1212226047"/>
    <nd ref="1212226166"/>
    <nd ref="1212226180"/>
    <nd ref="1212226130"/>
    <nd ref="1212226067"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Bonn"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="23"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="53229"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196618" version="2" timestamp="2011-03-21T20:19:24Z" changeset="7631407" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226110"/>
    <nd ref="1212226181"/>
    <nd ref="1212226107"/>
    <nd ref="1212226030"/>
    <nd ref="1212226125"/>
    <nd ref="1212226091"/>
    <nd ref="1212226208"/>
    <nd ref="1212226044"/>
    <nd ref="1212226127"/>
    <nd ref="1212226203"/>
    <nd ref="1212226085"/>
    <nd ref="1212226052"/>
    <nd ref="1212226042"/>
    <nd ref="1212226061"/>
    <nd ref="1212226038"/>
    <nd ref="1212226190"/>
    <nd ref="1212226139"/>
    <nd ref="1212226110"/>
    <tag k="amenity" v="school"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Marktschule"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196620" version="2" timestamp="2011-05-26T14:50:40Z" changeset="8254295" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226196"/>
    <nd ref="1212226130"/>
    <nd ref="1212226180"/>
    <nd ref="1212226040"/>
    <nd ref="1212226035"/>
    <nd ref="1212226196"/>
    <tag k="building" v="garages"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196621" version="2" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:21:17Z" changeset="7630100" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226041"/>
    <nd ref="1212226090"/>
    <nd ref="1212226171"/>
    <nd ref="1212226020"/>
    <nd ref="1212226041"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Bonn"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="23a"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="53229"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196625" version="2" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:21:18Z" changeset="7630100" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226133"/>
    <nd ref="1212226104"/>
    <nd ref="1212226043"/>
    <nd ref="1212226192"/>
    <nd ref="1212226133"/>
    <tag k="addr:city" v="Bonn"/>
    <tag k="addr:country" v="DE"/>
    <tag k="addr:housenumber" v="23b"/>
    <tag k="addr:postcode" v="53229"/>
    <tag k="addr:street" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196626" version="1" timestamp="2011-03-21T18:14:54Z" changeset="7630016" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226028"/>
    <nd ref="1212226024"/>
    <nd ref="1212226031"/>
    <nd ref="1212226159"/>
    <nd ref="1212226131"/>
    <nd ref="1212226069"/>
    <nd ref="1212226028"/>
    <tag k="building" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="leisure" v="sports_centre"/>
    <tag k="sport" v="multi"/>
  </way>
  <way id="105196629" version="2" timestamp="2011-05-26T14:50:40Z" changeset="8254295" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1212226087"/>
    <nd ref="1212226026"/>
    <nd ref="1212226144"/>
    <nd ref="1212226184"/>
    <nd ref="1212226087"/>
    <tag k="building" v="garages"/>
  </way>
  <way id="142380554" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:57Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw">
    <nd ref="1558201831"/>
    <nd ref="291438870"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="footway"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Mutter-Barat-StraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="142380557" version="3" timestamp="2012-05-13T23:29:39Z" changeset="11591622" uid="49785" user="mike67">
    <nd ref="1558201823"/>
    <nd ref="1558201815"/>
    <nd ref="1558201810"/>
    <nd ref="1558201808"/>
    <nd ref="1558201806"/>
    <nd ref="1558201807"/>
    <nd ref="1558201809"/>
    <nd ref="1647096076"/>
    <nd ref="1558201814"/>
    <nd ref="1751820951"/>
    <nd ref="1647096079"/>
    <nd ref="291435953"/>
    <nd ref="1558201813"/>
    <nd ref="1558201812"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
  </way>
  <way id="142380558" version="1" timestamp="2011-12-22T14:11:58Z" changeset="10179910" uid="116044" user="berndw">
    <nd ref="1558201806"/>
    <nd ref="291435957"/>
    <nd ref="1212226220"/>
    <nd ref="291435958"/>
    <nd ref="291435959"/>
    <nd ref="1212226021"/>
    <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="foot" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="service"/>
    <tag k="motorcar" v="private"/>
    <tag k="motorcycle" v="private"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Von-Ketteler-StraÃŸe"/>
  </way>

</osm>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this depends a bit on what context you're working in.  In general, you're presumably going to have some code iterating over the `way` elements, and within that some other code iterating over `nd` elements.  Fetch the `@ref` value from there and assign it to a variable, then write an XPath expression to find the `node` with that ID and return its `@lat` and `@lon` attributes.

In XQuery, for example, the following query returns the set of `way` elements with each `nd` child augmented with lat/lon information.

```
let $in := doc('/Users/cmsmcq/2012/misc/SO2/user1671.xml')
for $w in $in//way
return element {"way"} 
     { for $a in $w/@* return $a,
       for $n in $w/nd
       let $id := $n/@ref,
           $node := $in//node[@id=$id],
           $lat := $node/@lat,
           $lon := $node/@lon
       return <nd ref="{$id}" lat="{$lat}" lon="{$lon}"/>
     }
```

This is presumably not what you want (it drops the `tag` elements), but it may help you see the pattern you need.

It's very difficult (I think it's impossible, but I don't have a proof of that proposition) to do this in XPath by itself, because XPath has no way to refer, from within a predicate, to the node which was the context node before the left-bracket of the predicate reset the context node.  (That's what the XSLT `current()` function is for, and that's one of the things variable bindings are good for.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not currently doing this in code...but if you are correct, I  may need to. I'm importing the xml file through Drupal 7's feeds module and mapping the nd/@ref to a node reference field. I have the nodes already created using a different feed.  I want to add the lat and long value into a Geofield WKT field as a line so I can map the ways. If anyone has anything to add please do...

Answer (score 0):

Overpass API provides a new mode `out geom;` which embeds all ways' node lat/lon details right underneath the way element. Hence this rather complicated way of collecting node lat/lon details is no longer needed.

Check the Overpass Query Language documentation on wiki.openstreetmap.org for further  details.

For illustration, this is the result you would get for query `way(26577114);out geom;`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API"> <note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note> <meta osm_base="2014-10-13T19:08:02Z"/>

  <way id="26577114">
    <bounds minlat="50.7461387" minlon="7.1558430" maxlat="50.7468739" maxlon="7.1563067"/>
    <nd ref="291435953" lat="50.7468739" lon="7.1563067"/>
    <nd ref="1751820952" lat="50.7465981" lon="7.1562371"/>
    <nd ref="291435954" lat="50.7464770" lon="7.1561995"/>
    <nd ref="1751820953" lat="50.7463604" lon="7.1561245"/>
    <nd ref="1751820954" lat="50.7462630" lon="7.1560233"/>
    <nd ref="1751820955" lat="50.7461938" lon="7.1559261"/>
    <nd ref="291435955" lat="50.7461387" lon="7.1558430"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="residential"/>
    <tag k="lit" v="yes"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Rhedenstraße"/>   </way>

</osm>
```